# Stack Overflow pages take high CPU in Chrome when opened from restored session until visible

Tags: bug, stack-overflow

I recently noticed that with a freshly re-opened Chrome window (I have Chrome set to re-open my last opened tabs), all the hidden Stack Overflow question tabs are eating up nearly 100% of a CPU core each. As soon as each tab is switched to for the first time, though, the CPU usage goes back to the expected 0.

Screenshot (on a machine with 8 cores for reference):
[image: Chrome task manager]

This seems to only affect Stack Overflow pages (I tried with a gamedev.SE question and it was fine), so I'm not sure if I should ask here or at meta.stackoverflow.com.

Chrome version: 34.0.1847.116 m

**Edit:**

Some better steps to reproduce:

1. Open Chrome; make sure it's set to reopen your tabs from last time when reopened
2. Open a few Stack Overflow questions -- I'm using [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926046/is-there-a-way-to-bookmark-code-in-a-visual-studio-project) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808499/sqlite-extension-name) for testing. (I also have many other tabs open, e.g. lots of MSDN ones, but they don't appear to cause problems.)
3. Switch to a non-Stack Overflow tab.
4. Close Chrome
5. Re-open Chrome. Wait for all the tabs to finish loading.
6. Open the Chrome task manager (<kbd>Shift+Esc</kbd>) and check the CPU usage of the SO tabs -- zero, one, or both may be hogging a core (generally one in my tests).
7. Switch to the tab that's hogging CPU -- the CPU will reduce to normal.
8. Repeat a few times as necessary until the bug manifests. Result on my PC (before switching to the tabs):

[image: Chrome task manager]

Comment: Hmm, the more I try this, the less reproducible it becomes. It happened first for two question tabs, then one, now none. I'll keep trying to reproduce...

Comment: So, this is not happening with other sites when the browser is recovering from a crash?

Comment: @Oded: Nope, just stackoverflow, and apparently not every time, either (one out of two questions roughly every second time I try, so far).

Comment: Thing is, there are many factors that could be at fault here (current system load, network congestion, possible bug in the browser...) - and even you are unable to reproduce reliably (how are you crashing your Chrome so often?).

Comment: @Oded: I just restarted my PC. Nothing but the browser is running (albeit with many other tabs). I'm closing the browser cleanly, not crashing it -- I have Chrome set to re-open my last opened tabs when it starts.

Comment: OK, this is slightly less reproducible than I first thought. It happens almost every time I re-open my browser (but not *every* time), and it seems to mostly be just one question out of my two [test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808499/sqlite-extension-name) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926046/is-there-a-way-to-bookmark-code-in-a-visual-studio-project) (but which one seems to change randomly each time, and I saw both taking up a core each at one point). But it still happens often enough that I think it's a legitimate bug (though it could be Chrome and not SO, of course)

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this. Perhaps it is being caused by another tab being loaded, a user script, a corrupted install of chrome, or malfunctioning RAM. It would be nice to have a set of steps in order to reproduce the issue if possible.

Comment: Can you try to use ctrl+f5 on one of the SO questions to ensure you have the latest version of the javascript scripts just to make sure that isn't the cause?

Comment: @Travis: It might be another tab, but I'd rather not close them all just to test right now (this is my work PC). I just forced refreshed both question pages and tried again -- this time they both started using 100% of a core each. I don't have any user scripts or (besides 'Blank New Tab') any extensions. Chrome works fine otherwise. RAM is fine otherwise (plenty of programs and virtual machines opened, no errors/crashes so far). I'll add some better steps to reproduce.

Comment: No repro here, when I close and reopen all tabs take some CPU then they all reduce themselves back to 0, including Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Shadow: Hmm, must be something on my end then. I'll play around with it some more when I have some spare time.

Comment: @Cameron start by disabling browser extensions and userscripts, those have nasty habit of messing things up when least expected.

Comment: @Shadow: I have no userscripts installed, and only one small extension (which I've disabled for now).

Comment: same behavior here.  only for stack overflow and only sometimes.  Same steps to reproduce.  Happy to help debug if you need a test victim. ;-)

Comment: @khester: Yay, I'm not alone :-) Do you happen to have many tabs open? Because I do, and I have a suspicion it might be a race condition somewhere that only shows up under heavier loads...

Comment: @Cameron - the last time it happened to me I slowly started closing tabs (initially 10 tabs open) until only stack overflow was open - still pegged.  not sure if having other tabs open at start is a requirement.

Comment: This happens pretty reliably to me too.  Cursory Chrome profiling shows nothing obvious, but I didn't dig into it.  I'll note that my usual usage is "suspend laptop, move to different network, wake laptop", if that helps.